# How to get response text from error in jQuery AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, error-handling

I am making an AJAX call to call a WebService. The dataType is JSON. Take a look at my code:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "@Url.Action("serviceName", "Service")",
  type: "POST",
  async: "false",
  data: param,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(result) {
    console.log("serviceName successfull");
    if (result.Success === true) {
      console.log(result);
    }
    return (result);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    toastr.error('Error service failed');
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(jqXHR.always());
    console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
    console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
  }
});
```

The data is processed by the web service and runs into an error. I know that from debugging the WebService side, this error is thrown because of some values, but the JSON itself is valid. At this point the WebService returns an additional message to the client, saying what went wrong.

Unfortunately I am not able to get this useful error message inside the error handler function. All I get shown in my [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2diH7.png) is this. Seeing this "parsererror", the client thinks that the send JSON is not valid, which is not correct, it is valid.

I also know for sure that this message is sent, because calling the WebSerivce from a Python script and running into the same error, this message is accessible.
I have already tried a lot of different approaches, but nothing showed me the error-message.

I hope you have some suggestions!

Comment: Can you post your Json code ?

Comment: Can you please add the exact response from the request to the question. You can retrieve this from the network tab of the console after the requets completes

Comment: You should look at the json in the response via your devtools and add it to your question.

Comment: Looking inside my browser devTools -> Network -> Response -> it says "This request has no response data available"

Comment: @executable the JSON data itself is valid and the content not relevant for the problem

Comment: I found the issue, working with an MVC-project the Controllers used in this context failed, so the error-message never reached the ajax-error function
Thank you anyways for your suggestions!